# How about `__name__ != "__main__"` in Python?

Tags: python, python-import, python-importlib

I'm writing a Python script that is supposed to be imported. It has some plumbing to do and uses a function from itself. If I put this at the top of the script I have to put the function definition first and it gets ugly.

Is `__name__ != "__main__"` a proper solution to execute code on import? Or are there any other conventions for that?

Basically what I want to do is: Get definitions first and then run this code.

Here is an example to how it basically looks:

```py
import logging

def setup():
   global logger = logging.get_logger(__name__)  

def get_logger(name:str):
    # do magic
    # packed in a function to be reusable elsewhere
    return logging.get_logger(name)

if __name__ != "__main__":
    setup()
```

To clarify why: This is a `utils.py` with stuff being used in other scripts. One function it has is `get_logger(name: str)`. That function sets up a logger with all bells and whistles. In other scripts I call `get_logger(__name__)` to do it in one line. Now I want to call this within my `utils.py` as well. I don't want to call this at the bottom of the script, but at the top where it's nice and visible. However I can't just call the function before its definition.

Comment: A small code example says more than a thousand words of description.

Comment: Provide [mre], it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Also EVERY code at top level will be executed at import. `__name__ != "__main__"` is useless, unless your actual goal is NOT to execute specific part of the code when run as stand-alone script (i.e. as opposite to import).

Comment: I added some sample. Hope that helps to understand the question. Sorry if there was any confusion.

Comment: The script does nothing when run directly. However I feel the "plumbing" should be at the top of the script right after the imports. If I wouldn't do this it would say that "get_logger" is not defined. But if I put this at the bottom it's hard to see that this creates a logger.

Comment: It will raise `NameError` always, this `if` will not prevent the error, if you try to use `get_logger` before it is defined. Also _The script does nothing when run directly_ exactly because of this `if`

Comment: As far as I know, the `if __name__ == '__main__'` is always at the end, and it is fine. Not sure why in your case it should be an issue just because you have `!=` instead of `==`. Don't overthink.

Comment: @buran You a right, I missed to wrap it in a function as well. I edited the example.

Comment: Two points - note that you try to call `logging.get_logger()` and there is no such function in `logging` module. Note that this is not your function `get_logger`. There is `logging.getLogger()` module level function. Second - what's the purpose of wrapping it in a function when you can do the same inside the `if` in the bottom? And third - this `global` you added just now, is the cherry at the top of the cake.... and will cause error.

Comment: @buran right again, the example became I complete mess. though this back and forth mad me think about this. i guess there is no way but just executing my function at the end of a script

Comment: I'm not sure what the benefit you see in executing that line in the module you import rather than importing your module/function and execute that line in the module where it is imported. I may be missing something though. And again, I don't see the need of the `if`, unless you want to prevent that line being executed when run the script directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want code to run when the file is imported but *not* when it is run directly, `if __name__ != "__main__"` is perfectly fine. You're doing the opposite of the usual `if __name__ == "__main__": main()` thing after all.

Comment: `if name is main: main()` is NOT the "usual", `if __name__ == '__main__':` is. Note `name` vs `__name__` and `is` vs `==`

Comment: Yeah yeah that was pseudo-code; I'll update for clarity.